# Junit test causes Mysql Metadata lock

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, junit, metadata

I have the following test methods (based off previously created and working test cases):

`public class CommentGenericDaoHibernateImplTest {
    private Comment comment; 
    private ReqCandAssociation reqCandAssc;
    private JobReq JOBREQ;
    private Candidate CANDIDATE;

```
private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;
private GenericDao<Comment, Integer> dao;
private GenericDao<JobReq, Integer> reqDao;
private GenericDao<Candidate, Integer> candDao;
private GenericDao<ReqCandAssociation, Integer> reqCandDao;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Before
public void setUp() {


    JOBREQ = new JobReq("TTYL", "Title", "contract", "project", "laborCategory", "summary", "jobDescription", "status", "TTONumber", new Date(), new Date(), "location", "lead", "leadEmail", "reason", "duration", "recruiter", "openingType", new Date(), "f", "2");
    CANDIDATE = new Candidate("candName", "email", "phoneNum", "title", "mainStatus", new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), "none", "skillsSummary", "costRate", "clearanceType", new Date(), "contingentHire", "submittingCompany", "employingCompany", "5");
    reqCandAssc = new ReqCandAssociation(CANDIDATE, JOBREQ, "Hired");

    comment = new Comment("CommentGenericDaoHibernateImplTest TEST COMMENT", new Date(), reqCandAssc);

    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    reqDao = (GenericDaoHibernateImpl<JobReq, Integer>) ctx.getBean("jobReqDao");
    candDao = (GenericDaoHibernateImpl<Candidate, Integer>) ctx.getBean("candDao");
    reqCandDao = (GenericDaoHibernateImpl<ReqCandAssociation, Integer>) ctx.getBean("reqCandDao");
    dao = (GenericDaoHibernateImpl<Comment, Integer>) ctx.getBean("commentDao");

    reqDao.create(JOBREQ);
    candDao.create(CANDIDATE);
    reqCandDao.create(reqCandAssc);


}

@Test
public void testCreatingComment() {
    try {           
        Integer key = reqDao.create(comment);
        assertTrue("attachment not created successfully!", key > 0);
    } finally {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testRetrievingCommentByIdAfterCreate() {
    try {           
        Integer key = dao.create(comment);
        Comment retrievedComment = dao.read(key);
        assertEquals("Could not find attachment with id = "+key, retrievedComment, comment);
    } finally {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testUpdatingCommentAfterCreate() {
    try {

        Integer key = dao.create(comment);
        comment.setComment("ALTERED");
        dao.update(comment);
        Comment retrievedComment = dao.read(key);
        assertEquals("Could not update attachment with id = "+key, 
        comment.getComment(), retrievedComment.getComment());
    } finally {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testDeletingCommentAfterCreate() {
    try {

        comment.setCommentDate(new Date());
        Integer key = dao.create(comment);
        assertTrue("attachment not created successfully!", key > 0);

        dao.delete(comment);

        Comment queriedComment = dao.read(key);
        assertNull("Could not delete attachment with id = "+key, queriedComment);
    } finally {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testRetrievingAllCommentsAfterCreate() {
    try {           
        Integer key = dao.create(comment);
        assertTrue("attachment not created successfully!", key > 0);

        List<Comment> queriedAttachmentList = dao.findAll();
        assertEquals("Could not list all attachment", 1, queriedAttachmentList.size());
    } finally {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}`

which uses hibernate in methods like this:

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public PK create(T o) {
        Session hibernateSession = this.getSession();
        PK id = null;
        try {
            hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
            id = (PK) hibernateSession.save(o);
            hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            hibernateSession.close();
        }
        return id;
    }`

To act upon the DB.  Now a `Comment` entity is in a OneToMany with a ReqCandAssociation which in turn is the ManyToMany resolution table for a JobReq and Candidate.  So basically I need to create a JobReq, Candidate, then I can create a ReqCandAssociation, and then a comment to attach to One ReqCandAssociation objects.  However whenever I try to add more than one object to the database I get a `Waiting for table metadata lock` on the process in MySQL.

I have tried testing creating one entity at a time and it allows me to make a Candidate or a jobreq and add in a jobreq (instead of a comment, for testing) but once I try to add both a candidate and a job req then do something else I get the lock.  I've also tried adding these prerequisite objects in the `@Test` methods themselves instead of in the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after quite a bit of digging that if your test throws an error it locks the DB, for some reason these Junit tests don't show the syntax error highlights like normal classes and (seemed to) compile fine.  I had a misplaced value in one of my object constructors that led to the error.

Figured this out after a whole lot of strategically placed System.out.println()'s